# What's the benefit of wildcard generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

What benefit gives us the second signature method with wildcard `<?>`?

```
public static <T> void firstCheckList(List<T> myList, T obj)                
public static <T> void secondCheckList(List<?> myList, T obj)
```

Comment: I don't know about "benefit."  Those two lines of code are two totally different things.

Comment: Yes, I know it. The second line gives us more options for type. But I don't know when I should use the second line approach.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, there is some difference

Comment: If Im right, it's no sense to use "pure" `<?>`, but it's very useful in case like this `<? extend MyType>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is that in the 2nd option the list members don't need to be the same type as obj

If there is a correlation between myList and obj (type-wise) it is best to use the 1st option, if there isn't use the 2nd option